# Google Chrome - How to kill streaming capture from iframe which was playing mjpeg stream?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, iframe, windows-8

I am capturing live streaming via an iframe which is 3 to 4MB of 720p

```
$('#iframe_display_modules').attr('src', 'http://192.168.0.1/AXIS/SecurityCamera_Watch/live.mjpeg');
```

Playing the stream cause Google Chrome in horrible condition like slowing down with other activity.

Finally i kill the iframe using following code:

```
$('#iframe_display_modules').attr('src', '');
```

But then i verify if its closed or not via chrome://net-internals > timeline and i still see Google Chrome is keep downloading live stream even i removed it from iFRame as a result after few hours the system crash or get frozen.

How do we kill the stream please and be 100% sure its for sure killed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried removing the element? Like this

```
$('#iframe_display_modules').remove();
```